# How do I get Emacs to fill sentences, but not paragraphs?

Tags: emacs, latex, fill

I've [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539791/tips-for-collaboratively-editing-a-latex-document/539848#539848) at least two [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193298/best-practices-in-latex/196724#196724) on StackOverflow to insert newlines between sentences when editing LaTeX documents. The reason being that the practice facilitates source control, `diff`ing, and collaborative editing.

I'm basically convinced, but I'm lazy, and I don't want to have to think about it.

So I'm searching for some emacs incantation to handle it for me. Could be a minor mode, could be a set of variables that need to be set.

I think what I *don't* want is

- Soft wrapping of text (say using the [longlines](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/LongLines) and `(set long-lines-auto-wrap 't)`). This is because I don't want to impose requirements on my collaborators' editors, and *I* sometimes use other unix tools to examine these files.

I think what I *do* want is

- For `fill-paragraph` to fill between newlines that look like they mark the end of a sentence.
- A solution that works with `auto-fill-mode` would be a bonus.

That is:

> chat chat chat.
>   A new sentence
>   with goofed up wrapping that needs to be fixed.
>   Mumble mumble

Transformed to:

> chat chat chat.
>   A new sentence with goofed up wrapping that needs to be fixed.
>   Mumble mumble

Your comments and suggestions are appreciated.

---

Edit: The suggestion by [Jouni K. Seppänen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/539984/how-do-i-get-emacs-to-fill-sentences-but-not-paragraphs/540760#540760) pointed me at `LaTeX-fill-break-at-separators`, which suggests that emacs almost knows how to do this already. Anyway, I'm off to read some code, and will report back. Thanks again.

---

More general version of the same question: [Editor showdown: Maintain newlines at the ends of sentences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/543379/editor-showdown-maintain-newlines-at-the-ends-of-sentences). Thanks, [dreeves](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4234/dreeves).

Comment: It should be possible to just do the equivalent of M-^ (`delete-indentation`) on the beginning of each line that does not start a sentence. But why don't you want soft wrapping?

Comment: "why don't you want soft wrapping?" Hmmm. I don't know, really. It's bugged me for a long time. Why _do_ I want soft wrapping?

Comment: Do you think it would be worth generalizing this question so people can give solutions for other editors besides emacs?  It's also more general than LaTeX, come to think of it. All the reasons for doing this apply to HTML documents as well, for example.

Comment: I went ahead and added the more general question.  I'm happy to delete it if you want to fold it in with this one.

Comment: It would have been reasonable, indeed, but real life intervened and I was away from my computer... So, I linked to your version.

Answer (score 10):

Here's [what I use](http://procrastiblog.com/2007/11/25/style-guidelines-for-people/), which was mostly cribbed from [Luca de Alfaro](http://luca.cse.ucsc.edu/Style_guidelines_for_student_co-authors):

```
(defun fill-sentence ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (or (eq (point) (point-max)) (forward-char))
    (forward-sentence -1)
    (indent-relative t)
    (let ((beg (point))
          (ix (string-match "LaTeX" mode-name)))
      (forward-sentence)
      (if (and ix (equal "LaTeX" (substring mode-name ix)))
          (LaTeX-fill-region-as-paragraph beg (point))
        (fill-region-as-paragraph beg (point))))))
```

I bind this to `M-j` with

```
(global-set-key (kbd "M-j") 'fill-sentence)
```

The references to `"LaTeX"` are for [AUCTeX](http://www.gnu.org/software/auctex/) support. If you don't use AUCTeX, the `let` can be simplified to

```
(let (beg (point))
  (forward-sentence)
  (fill-region-as-paragraph beg (point)))
```

Comment: I use AUCTeX. And I'll give this a try.

Comment: your second `let` doesn't have enough parens around `beg`

Comment: `fill-sentence` fills paragraphs with 80 column limit, is it normal?

Answer (score 5):

I have been meaning to do this forever and I recently found [this blog post](http://pleasefindattached.blogspot.com/2011/12/emacsauctex-sentence-fill-greatly.html) which worked fairly well for me.  So here is (a slightly modified version of) what I have been using for a few days.

```lisp
(defun auto-fill-by-sentences ()
  (if (looking-back (sentence-end))
      ;; Break at a sentence
      (progn
        (LaTeX-newline)
        t)
    ;; Fall back to the default
    (do-auto-fill)))
(add-hook 'LaTeX-mode-hook (lambda () (setq auto-fill-function 'auto-fill-by-sentences)))

;; Modified from http://pleasefindattached.blogspot.com/2011/12/emacsauctex-sentence-fill-greatly.html
(defadvice LaTeX-fill-region-as-paragraph (around LaTeX-sentence-filling)
  "Start each sentence on a new line."
  (let ((from (ad-get-arg 0))
        (to-marker (set-marker (make-marker) (ad-get-arg 1)))
        tmp-end)
    (while (< from (marker-position to-marker))
      (forward-sentence)
      ;; might have gone beyond to-marker---use whichever is smaller:
      (ad-set-arg 1 (setq tmp-end (min (point) (marker-position to-marker))))
      ad-do-it
      (ad-set-arg 0 (setq from (point)))
      (unless (or (looking-back "^\\s *")
                  (looking-at "\\s *$"))
        (LaTeX-newline)))
    (set-marker to-marker nil)))
(ad-activate 'LaTeX-fill-region-as-paragraph)
```

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I've been very slow to respond to new answers on this questions; I've had other things at the top of my work queue. This code works very nicely indeed when I'm typing new text---it is exactly what I asked for. It's not handling existing text with sentences starting in mid line on `fill-paragraph`, but does handle them if I type a space at the start of each sentence. Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean that it thinks sentences should be separated by double spaces?  That can be changed by setting `sentence-end-double-space`.  If you mean that you want it to break unconditionally after a `.`, `!`, `?` etc. then you could change the value of `sentence-end`, or change the call to `sentence-end` to whatever regexp you prefer.

Comment: For some reason this solution still wraps long lines for me - it does however add a newline after the period. How can I make it not wrap within a single sentence?

Comment: @icks Hmm.  This isn't the same as I have in my .emacs, so they must have diverged at some point.  Try changing the `(do-auto-fill)` to `nil` and see if that helps.

Answer (score 4):

If you put a comment marker at the end of each sentence, Emacs knows not to move the next line inside the comment:

```
chat chat chat.%
A new sentence
with goofed up wrapping that needs to be fixed.%
Mumble mumble%
```

Then M-q fills each sentence separately, at least in AUCTeX 11.85. (If you test this in Emacs, there seems to be a bug where if this is the first paragraph in the buffer and you type M-q, you get an error message. Just put a newline before the text to work around it.)

If you don't want to type the comment characters, you could take LaTeX-fill-paragraph and modify it so that sentence-ending punctuation at end of line works similarly to comments.

Comment: OK. Not what I had been expecting, but it would certainly work.

Comment: Isn't this is more trouble than just switching autofill off?  What use is M-q in this situation?

Comment: That will gobble the spaces between sentences.  You need `...chat. %` etc. with a space before the `%`

Comment: How can I modify it so that sentence-ending punctuation at end of line works similarly to comments?

Answer (score 3):

```
(defun wrap-at-sentences ()
  "Fills the current paragraph, but starts each sentence on a new line."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    ;; Select the entire paragraph.
    (mark-paragraph)
    ;; Move to the start of the paragraph.
    (goto-char (region-beginning))
    ;; Record the location of the end of the paragraph.
    (setq end-of-paragraph (region-end))
    ;; Wrap lines with 'hard' newlines (i.e., real line breaks).
    (let ((use-hard-newlines 't))
      ;; Loop over each sentence in the paragraph.
      (while (< (point) end-of-paragraph)
        ;; Determine the region spanned by the sentence.
        (setq start-of-sentence (point))
        (forward-sentence)
        ;; Wrap the sentence with hard newlines.
        (fill-region start-of-sentence (point))
        ;; Delete the whitespace following the period, if any.
        (while (char-equal (char-syntax (preceding-char)) ?\s)
          (delete-char -1))
        ;; Insert a newline before the next sentence.
        (insert "\n")))))

(global-set-key (kbd "M-q") 'wrap-at-sentences)
```

Comment: For my personal use I removed the `(insert "\n")`. Thanks for that! This is the best solution for me so far.

Answer (score 2):

May not work in all circumstances, but:

```
(defun my-fill-sentence ()
  "Fill sentence separated by punctuation or blank lines."
  (interactive)
  (let (start end)
    (save-excursion
      (re-search-backward "\\(^\\s-*$\\|[.?!]\\)" nil t)
      (skip-syntax-forward "^w")
      (setq start (point-at-bol)))
    (save-excursion
      (re-search-forward "\\(^\\s-*$\\|[.?!]\\)" nil t)
      (setq end (point-at-eol)))
    (save-restriction
      (narrow-to-region start end)
      (fill-paragraph nil))))
```

To make it work with `auto-fill-mode`, add `(setq normal-auto-fill-function 'my-fill-sentence)` to your LaTeX mode hook (I think).

Comment: It looks like the fill-paragraph there at the end is sticking in a newline I don't want. But is does work only on the sentence under the point.

Comment: It works on your example ... is there a different example that shows the problem?

Comment: Um. Didn't work for me on the same example. If I put the put after "sentence" an invoke it I get the second sentence nicely filled and a newline before "Mumble mumble". Looking in my '.emacs' I find a lot of cruft. I'll turn it off and try again.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you know elisp.

There are a few approaches you can take:

- Hook into `auto-fill-mode`.  There are a lot of hard-coded
   conditionals there, so it might not work for you.  You can
   potentially play with `auto-fill-function` and see if you have
   the hook you need there.
- Make a character (probably `.`) "electric" so that when you press
   it, it inserts itself and then calls a function to determine how
   to fill the line you're on.
- Set an `after-change-hook` to call a function that determines how
   to fill the sentence.  This function will be called after every
   change to the buffer, so do it efficiently.  (This mechanism is
   used by `font-lock`, so don't worry about it too much.  It sounds
   slow, but really isn't -- people type slowly.)

Once you have hooked in at the right place, you just have to implement
the filling logic.  The source for `sentence-at-point` (from `thingatpt`) may be
instructive.

Anyway, I've never heard of anyone doing this... but it is definitely possible.  Like most things in Emacs, it's just a Simple Matter Of Programming.

Comment: I've never given lisp the time it requires, so I am very weak there.

Comment: 'k.  This may be the perfect learning project, since it is straightforward, but not "easy".

Answer (score 1):

If the other answers are *too* automatic, here's a semiautomatic approach.
It's basically what you would do repeatedly if you were going to manually reformat, but condensed so you can hit a single key repeatedly instead.

```
;; - go to the end of the line,
;; - do ^d to suck the previous line onto this one, 
;; - make sure there's only one space between the now-concatenated
;;   lines, and then 
;; - jump to the end and hit space so that (with auto-fill-mode)
;;   the line nicely rewraps itself:
;;   (turn on auto-fill-mode with M-x auto-fill-mode)
(defalias 'fill-sentence
  (read-kbd-macro "C-e C-d SPC M-x just- one- space RET C-e SPC <backspace>"))

(define-key global-map [f4] 'fill-sentence)  ; or whatever key you like
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Chris Conway's macro a lot but it only works after you manually line-break each sentence.  I'm a lazy guy so I want emacs to do it for me.  This morning I finally sat down and looked into the problem.  The solution I have now is to hack the built-in macro `fill-region-as-paragraph`.

After applying the following hack, a new option `newline-after-sentence` will be set to true.  The standard `M-q` (`fill-paragraph`) will automatically fill *and create line-breaks between* sentences.  Note that tests are only done with GNU Emacs 23.3.1 — use it at your own risk.

The full macro is long so I won't post it here.  The idea is to add the following loops in `fill-region-as-paragraph`

```
...

;; Insert a line break after each sentence
(while (< (point) to)
  (forward-sentence)
  (if (< (point) to) (fill-newline)))

;; This is the actual filling loop.
(goto-char from)
(let (sentbeg sentend)
  (while (< (point) to)
    (setq sentbeg (point))
    (end-of-line)
    (setq sentend (point))
    (fill-one-line sentbeg sentend justify) ;; original filling loop
    (forward-line)))))

...
```

You can find the full macro in [my git repository](http://fermi.mycloudnas.com/cgit.cgi/fill/tree/hack.el).  Some details are also written in [my blog](http://fermi.mycloudnas.com/2011/05/fill-hack/).  In case you don't want to read my poor English, you can simply use

```
$ curl http://fermi.mycloudnas.com/cgit.cgi/fill/plain/hack.el >> ~/.emacs
```

to append the hack to your `~/.emacs` and give it a try.  Comments and bug reports are all welcome.

Comment: Website down, and wayback machine does not have it archived.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach would be to leave your .tex file as is, and use a tool like latexdiff
(described in [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65453/track-changes-in-latex) StackExchange post) instead of Unix diff. This produces a .tex file with Word-style track changes marks, and handles whitespace correctly so you don't have to worry about where your sentences end.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote the following which loops over a region and inserts newlines.  Instead of using `forward-sentence` which didn't work for me, I use `re-search-forward "[.?!][]\"')}]*\\(  \\)"`, which finds all sentences followed only by two spaces (the regexp is a modified `sentence-end`).  The newline is made using `newline-and-indent`.

```
(defun fill-sentences-in-paragraph ()
  "Put a newline at the end of each sentence in paragraph."
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (mark-paragraph)
    (call-interactively 'fill-sentences-in-region)))

(defun fill-sentences-in-region (start end)
  "Put a newline at the end of each sentence in region."
  (interactive "*r")
  (call-interactively 'unfill-region)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char start)
    (while (re-search-forward "[.?!][]\"')}]*\\(  \\)" end t)
      (newline-and-indent))))
```

To be able to fix improperly formatted text such as the example "chat chat chat...", `fill-sentences-in-region` first calls [`unfill-region`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnfillRegion) which gets rid of sentence-breaking whitespace:

```
   (defun unfill-region (beg end)
      "Unfill the region, joining text paragraphs into a
       single logical line.  This is useful, e.g., for use
       with 'visual-line-mode'."
      (interactive "*r")
      (let ((fill-column (point-max)))
        (fill-region beg end)))
```

I use `visual-line-mode` and replace my default paragraph fill `M-q` to `fill-sentences-in-paragraph` with `(global-set-key "\M-q" 'fill-sentences-in-paragraph)`.